# В запросе получается лишняя запатая

Tags: python, запрос

```
postcursor.execute('SELECT customer_id FROM REQUEST')
postselect_request_id_result = postcursor.fetchall()
for customer_id in postselect_request_id_result:
```

Проблема в том, что в выдаче, после каждого числа появляется какая-то запятая
[(2,), (6,)]

вопрос - почему?

Comment: Конструкция вида (2,) - это "одноместный" кортеж, т.е. нечто типа (1,2), но с одним элементом. Так что запятая не лишняя, без нее это будут просто цифры в скобках, а не кортежи.

Comment: @Suliman3, вы же понимаете, что это просто представление, а в качестве данных вам приходят вполне обычные числа, где символов типа запятой нет вообще?

---

Тюплы (или кортежи) принято писать с такой вот запятой в конце. Необходимость подобного форматирования вызвана тем, что тюпл из одного элемента иначе невозможно отличить от группирующих скобок. Чтобы новички на этом не спотыкались, да и чтобы мозг при продолжении написании уже существующего кортежа не отвлекался на "закрытие" уже написанного элемента, принято в конце писать запятую.

Comment: А как мне это все в список преобразовать? Или есть какой-то способ проверить входит ли чисто в кортеж?

Comment: @Suliman3

    >>> a = (3,)
    >>> 3 in a
    True
    >>> 5 in a
    False

Comment: Что-то не получается:

  print "-----++------"
  print fireselect_request_id_result
  if 2 in fireselect_request_id_result:
   print "2 is HERE!"
  # print customer_id
  print "-=-=-=-="
  
Вот вывод:
-----++------
[(2,), (6,)]
-=-=-=-=

Comment: @Suliman3, потому что `fireselect_request_id_result` - это список, как можно заметить по выводу.

    >>> a = [(2,), (6,),]
    >>> (2,) in a
    True

Но вообще так делать не надо, тюпл, насколько понимаю - это строка из таблицы, и проверять надо, итерируя по элементам списка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tuple data structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)
[tuple()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple)
так вот о запятой:
запятая в случае с круглыми скобками говорит не только пользователю, но не самому интерпретатору, что это итерируемый объект, а не группирующие скобки
как было сказано выше: считай, что это список [[2],[6]] за тем исключением, что он не изменяемый (можно читать, но писать в него нельзя)
а в вашем случае (работая с "сырым курсором") могу посоветовать такую фишку:

```
cur.execute("SQL STATEMENT")
columns = map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description)
for row in cur.fetchall():
    row_as_dict = dict(zip(columns, row))
    do_something()
```

удачи

Comment: Я не совсем понял что этот код делает...

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле никакой запятой нету, питон просто так отображает кортежи из одного елемента.

представьте что это выглядит как [[2], [6]]